# How to merge same table with different conditions

Tags: sql, union, teradata, union-all

I need to write a query to produce a result to display the `OLD_ACCOUNT_ID` when available else `NULL` and the `NEW_ACCOUNT_ID` when available else `NULL` from the same table based on the conditions.  I tried a query like below but this does not produce the data in separate columns as `OLD` and `NEW`. Can somebody please help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT     
A.ACCOUNT_ID as NEW_ACCOUNT_ID, 
A.ACTIVE_FLAG,A.DATA_ID 
FROM Table  A
WHERE DATA_SOURCE_PROVIDER_ID='X' 
AND ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' 
and DATA_ID= '12345678'
union 
SELECT DISTINCT B.ACCOUNT_ID AS OLD_ACCOUNT_ID,
B.ACTIVE_FLAG,B.DATA_ID
FROM Table  B
WHERE DATA_SOURCE_PROVIDER_ID='X' 
AND  ACTIVE_FLAG='N' 
and DATA_ID= '12345678'
```

Comment: do you want to see both `OLD_ACCOUNT_ID` and `NEW_ACCOUNT_ID` for some records?

Comment: MySQL or Teradata? Have you considered using COALESCE()?

Comment: Its Teradata and Yes i want to see both OLD and NEW. I want to see OLD when available else NULL and i want to see NEW when available else NULL.

Comment: how `old_account` is related to `new_account`? if they have same `12345678`. That means in your query result you are expecting to get 1 record with `old` and `new` account_id for defined `DATA_ID= '12345678'`?

Comment: OLD_ACCOUNT is available only when the FLAG is 'N' whereas NEW_ACCOUNT is available when FLAG is 'Y'.So i want to display the records as OLD and NEW accounts in a single query. In my case i just gave an example.We are expecting two records.One for the FLAG when its Y and one when the flag is N.So when the FLAG is N the NEW should be displayed as NULL and when the flag is Y OLD should be NULL.

Comment: provide please raw data set and expected result set which can illustrate of what you are trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case

```
select DISTINCT  
  case ACTIVE_FLAG when 'Y'  then ACCOUNT_ID end as NEW_ACCOUNT_ID, 
  case ACTIVE_FLAG when 'N'  then ACCOUNT_ID end as OLD_ACCOUNT_ID, 
  ACTIVE_FLAG,D
  DATA_ID 
from Table
whene DATA_ID= '12345678';
```